# How can I toggle multiple divs on click

Tags: toggleclass, jquery

I've previously asked a similar question to this, the answers of which partially solved my issue.

However now I need to expand on the code.

This code toggles the visibility of the divs when there are only two, but when adding a third, it shows both the second and third sets of divs together when I want to show each set  individually'

This fiddle shows what currently happens;
http://jsfiddle.net/richarde/vCjPL/

jQuery

```
$('.media-thumb a').click(function(){
    $('div[class^="media"]').toggleClass('is-hidden');
    return false;
});
```

Markup (the click event is bound to anchor of these divs)

```
<div class="media-thumb ">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Link 1</a></p>
</div>
<div class="media-thumb is-hidden">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Link 2</a></p>
</div>
<div class="media-thumb is-hidden">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Link 3</a></p>
</div>
```

Now I need to expand on the above and I'm not sure my current approach is the best. What could I do to make this work in my situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be better if you will change this fiddle, add some css and show us what you want http://jsfiddle.net/KwwPS/

Comment: I've added a FIDDLE to show the current behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, clicking on 1st link, should make 2nd div appear and clicking on 2nd link, should make 3rd div appear and so on.

If so, then try this:

```
$('.media-thumb a').click(function(){
    var parentDiv=$(this).parents('div.media-thumb');
    $(parentDiv).toggleClass('is-hidden');
    if($(parentDiv).next('div.media-thumb').length){
       //there is next div.media-thumb; make it visible
       $(parentDiv).next('div.media-thumb').toggleClass('is-hidden'); 
    }else{
        //back to first div
        $('div.media-thumb:first').toggleClass('is-hidden');
    }
    return false;
});​
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sX9M/1/)

Now depending on whether you want the divs to take up space or not, make your css class `.is-hidden{ visibility: hidden}` or `.is-hidden{display: none}`

Comment: To clarify, what should happen is clicking the visible div should replace it with the second and clicking the second should replace it with the third. This should also happen for the divs associated with the second and third

Comment: @Thalis-Kalfigkopoulos this looks very promising, I also have other divs that are associated with the one the click is bound to. How can I capture these as well?

Answer (score 1):

#### Update: I completely changed the answer based on new information added to the question.

It sounds like the `<a>` elements should act like a "next" buttons.

I changed the HTML to have the third elements:

```
<!-- thumbs -->
<div class="media-thumb ">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Link 1</a></p>
</div>
<div class="media-thumb is-hidden">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Link 2</a></p>
</div>
<div class="media-thumb is-hidden">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" />
    <p><a href="#">Link 3</a></p>
</div>

<!-- images -->
<div class="media pull-left">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="media pull-left is-hidden">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="media pull-left is-hidden">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>

<!-- text -->
<div class="media-aside">
    <h4>heading 4</h4>
    <p>Text...</p>
    <p class="call-to-action"><a href="someurl">url</a></p>
</div>
<div class="media-aside is-hidden">
    <h4>heading 5</h4>
    <p>Paragraph...</p>
    <p class="call-to-action"><a href="someurl">url</a></p>
</div>
<div class="media-aside is-hidden">
    <h4>heading 6</h4>
    <p>Paragraph...</p>
    <p class="call-to-action"><a href="someurl">url</a></p>
</div>​
```

This JavaScript will cycle through the elements. If "Link 1" is clicked, then "Link 2", the second `img.media.pull-left` image and the second `div.media-aside` will be shown. If "Link 2" is clicked, the third elements from the thumbs, images and text sections will be show, etc.

```
var $divs = $('.media-thumb'),
    $imgs = $('.media'),
    $txts = $('.media-aside'),
    sets = [],
    max = $divs.length,
    cur = 0,
    i = 0,
    $temp;

// create jQuery objects that contains the .media-thumb, .media,
// and .media-aside HTML elements that should be showing at the
// same time. IE, a jQuery object with the 1st .media-thumb, the 1st
// .media, etc.

for (; i < max; i++) {
    sets[i] = $divs.eq(i)
        .add($imgs.eq(i))
        .add($txts.eq(i));
}

// when the <a> is clicked, turn off the current set
// and turn on the next set
$divs.on('click', 'a', function() {
    sets[cur].addClass('is-hidden');
    cur = ++cur % max;
    sets[cur].removeClass('is-hidden');
});
```

A jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TvK53/

Answer (score 0):

And if i understand correctly what you want, this example is something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/UYLkh/

```
$('.media-thumb a').each(function(key, el){
    $(el).click(function(){
        $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('is-hidden');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately when I run this code it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried fiddle i provided? it highlights div you clicked on, is this what you wanted? or you want to hide all divs except one you have clicked?